# Missing Dependencies Installing NumPy 1.9 for Python 3.4.1 32-bit on Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, numpy, amd-processor

I cannot seem to get NumPy 1.9.0 with Python 3.4.1 32-bit on a Windows 7 AMD 64-bit machine.

I download the package, unzip it, and run:

```
python setup.py install
```

Here are the messages I get in the command shell.

I think my problem is that I don't have an Intel machine with MLK binaries available, because I have an AMD processor.  I've tried a number of Google search results; no joy.

Any advice on how to make this successful?

```
F:\Tools\numpy-1.9.0>python setup.py install
Running from numpy source directory.
F:\Tools\python-3.4.1\lib\distutils\dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'test_suite'
  warnings.warn(msg)
non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
non-existing path in 'numpy\\f2py': 'docs'
non-existing path in 'numpy\\f2py': 'f2py.1'
F2PY Version 2
blas_opt_info:
blas_mkl_info:
  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['F:\\Tools\\python-3.4.1\\lib', 'C:\\', 'F:\\Tools\\python-3.4.1\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_info:
  libraries openblas not found in ['F:\\Tools\\python-3.4.1\\lib', 'C:\\', 'F:\\Tools\\python-3.4.1\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['F:\\Tools\\python-3.4.1\\lib', 'C:\\', 'F:\\Tools\\python-3.4.1\\libs
']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_info:
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['F:\\Tools\\python-3.4.1\\lib', 'C:\\', 'F:\\Tools\\python-3.4.1\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

F:\Tools\numpy-1.9.0\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1526: UserWarning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
blas_info:
  libraries blas not found in ['F:\\Tools\\python-3.4.1\\lib', 'C:\\', 'F:\\Tools\\python-3.4.1\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

F:\Tools\numpy-1.9.0\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1535: UserWarning:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
blas_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

F:\Tools\numpy-1.9.0\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1538: UserWarning:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
    the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
  NOT AVAILABLE

non-existing path in 'numpy\\lib': 'benchmarks'
lapack_opt_info:
openblas_lapack_info:
  libraries openblas not found in ['F:\\Tools\\python-3.4.1\\lib', 'C:\\', 'F:\\Tools\\python-3.4.1\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

lapack_mkl_info:
mkl_info:
  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['F:\\Tools\\python-3.4.1\\lib', 'C:\\', 'F:\\Tools\\python-3.4.1\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in F:\Tools\python-3.4.1\lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in F:\Tools\python-3.4.1\lib
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in F:\Tools\python-3.4.1\libs
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in F:\Tools\python-3.4.1\libs
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_info:
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in F:\Tools\python-3.4.1\lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in F:\Tools\python-3.4.1\lib
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in F:\Tools\python-3.4.1\libs
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in F:\Tools\python-3.4.1\libs
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

F:\Tools\numpy-1.9.0\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1432: UserWarning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
lapack_info:
  libraries lapack not found in ['F:\\Tools\\python-3.4.1\\lib', 'C:\\', 'F:\\Tools\\python-3.4.1\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

F:\Tools\numpy-1.9.0\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1443: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
    the LAPACK environment variable.
  warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
lapack_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

F:\Tools\numpy-1.9.0\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1446: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
  NOT AVAILABLE

F:\Tools\python-3.4.1\lib\distutils\dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running install
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
running build_src
build_src
building py_modules sources
building library "npymath" sources
No module named 'numpy.distutils.msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

F:\Tools\numpy-1.9.0>
```

Comment: Are you aware of [this site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)? It's so much easier than trying to compile modules by hand on Windows...

Comment: First, who told you that MKL doesn't work on AMD processors? Intel has a whole big thing about how they've optimized it specifically to work better with the "limitations" of their competitors chips than MathCore.

Comment: Second, you don't need MKL; it just makes things faster. That's why none of the errors are about MKL. The errors are about `msvccompiler` and `vcvarsall.bat`. Do you have a C compiler? What instructions are you following that didn't mention that you'd need one?

Comment: If you don't have a C compiler, follow the instructions to get and install one. If you do have one, but you're still getting the same error, search this site for `[python] vcvarsall.bat`; there are about 3 different problems you could have, all of which already have great answers.

Comment: I'm guessing.  I downloaded the package, unzipped, and installed.  Can you point me to more detailed instructions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to try and build NumPy on a Windows machine, good for you. However, if you want to **use** NumPy on a Windows machine, head over to Christoph Gohlke's [Python Extension Packages for Windows](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) repository. He has MKL-linked versions of NumPy for 32- and 64-bit Intel/AMD processors, as well as a ton of other related modules, mainly for scientific and numeric computing. You can find numpy [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy). Download the 32-bit `.exe` for your version of Python, run the installer, and you're all set.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful and will save me time with future module installs.