# Trying to install numpy 1.9.2 into Python 3.3

Tags: python, windows, numpy

I tried to install through powershell, but got this message:

```
No module named 'numpy.distutils.msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

If I use the `.exe` offered by numpy website, got a message saying `Python 3.3 could not be found`.

How could I solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Missing Dependencies Installing NumPy 1.9 for Python 3.4.1 32-bit on Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26290259/missing-dependencies-installing-numpy-1-9-for-python-3-4-1-32-bit-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your environment variables. Go to computer and system properties and see if there is a variable for python and set its path properly, which will resolve the .exe error.

Comment: Yes I set up the path already, I followed the youtube :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ddpYVA-7wq4

Comment: I tried to use powershell after I set up the path. So I don't know what's going on....

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this by installing pip. Then install a numpy .whl file from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ with "pip install ****.whl"